# I met this Error in Unity Engine while use mixed reality(MRTK)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

Hello I meet many errors while doing my project.

[image]

It says:

1.DllNotFoundException: Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.dll assembly: type: member:(null)
Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.SceneObserver+<>c.b__4_0 () (at Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.sceneunderstanding@7bfd3a8ea18c/Editor/Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.cs:1179)

2.Couldn't access Scene Understanding Observer! Please make sure the current build target is set to Universal Windows Platform. Visit https://learnmicrosoft.com/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/spatial-awareness/scene-understanding for more information.

[image]

I already set Universeal Windows Platform but, error appears like this.

what is your opinion on this?

+)

I found something.

[image]

When scene start this menu is automatically off. I turn on that menu at inspector after start game then it works good.

Howerver, I think this code turn off that menu.

```
  public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.SceneObserverAccessStatus> RequestAccessAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.SceneObserverAccessStatus result;
            Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.NativeLibraryHelpers.CheckStatus(Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.NativeLibrary.su_scene_observer_request_access_async(out result));
            return result;
        });
    }
```

So,I try to reform this code but, it throws error too. I think 'dil' problem is main reason of this situation.

++)

I solved this problem add this code. I choice turn on that menu forcely by code and ignore that error.

```
  GameObject.Find("MixedRealityToolkit").GetComponent<MixedRealityToolkit>().enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem add this code. I choice turn on that menu forcely by code and ignore that error.

```
GameObject.Find("MixedRealityToolkit").GetComponent<MixedRealityToolkit>().enabled = true;
```